# hide parameters passing to controller in address bar (URL rewrite or something else)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Event Overview", "{city}/{type}/{id}",
                            new {city="LA", controller = "BaseEvent", action = "EventOverview"}, new {city = new CityConstraint()});

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And, several links on my site:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Make", "EventOverview", "BaseEvent", new { id = eventInfo.Key.OID, type = eventInfo.Key.XPObjectType.TypeName.GetShortTypeName(), activeTab = "#scheduleLink", session = eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].SessionId, hall = eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].HallId, client = eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].BasePlace.PremieraClientId}, null)

@Html.ActionLink("Make", "EventOverview", "BaseEvent", new { id = eventInfo.Key.OID, type = eventInfo.Key.XPObjectType.TypeName.GetShortTypeName(), activeTab = "#scheduleLink",  }, null)
```

This is `EventOverview action:

```
 public ActionResult EventOverview(int id, string type, string activeTab,string hall, string session, string client, string count)
        {
            var model = CreateEventViewData<EventViewData>(id, type);
            model.ActiveTab = activeTab;
            model.ScheduleCount = count;
            model.SessionId = session;
            model.HallId = hall;
            model.ClientId = client;
            return View("Controls/EventsInfo/EventInfo", model);
        }
```

In the first link passing many parameters, and all shows in browser's address field:
This is for firts link:

```
http://localhost:62291/LA/Film/36?activeTab=%23scheduleLink&session=15&hall=65&client=2&count=1
```

This is for second link:

```
http://localhost:62291/LA/Film/36?activeTab=%23scheduleLink
```

I want something like that:

```
http://localhost:62291/LA/Film/36
```

What ways to hide parameters in an address line are?

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var link = $(".btn_buy_ticket").find("a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();            
            $.post($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    })

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EventOverview(int id) // just for test
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EventOverview", new {id = id});
        }

        public ActionResult EventOverview(int id, string type, string activeTab,string hall, string session, string client, string count)
        {
            var model = CreateEventViewData<EventViewData>(id, type);
            model.ActiveTab = activeTab;
            model.ScheduleCount = count;
            model.SessionId = session;
            model.HallId = hall;
            model.ClientId = client;
            return View("Controls/EventsInfo/EventInfo", model);
        }
```

All actions are called, but my  `EventInfo` view not loaded.

Comment: If you need the values from the parameters, you cannot 'hide' them, you have to get them back to the server somehow.  You can either a) POST them to the server or b) send them in your URL, do what you do and then redirect to a controller/action without most of them specified, storing the data you need in TempData or Session. Not too many options here when you need data from the client.

Comment: @Tommy: I wrote a handler to this link and do the following: prevent default and do post request, in the action I call `RedirectToAction`. See updateв question, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use POST instead of GET. So you could replace the link with a form containing hidden fields for the parameters that you don't want to appear in the query string:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EventOverview", "BaseEvent", new { id = eventInfo.Key.OID, type = eventInfo.Key.XPObjectType.TypeName.GetShortTypeName() }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.Hidden("activeTab", "#scheduleLink")
    @Html.Hidden("session", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].SessionId)
    @Html.Hidden("hall", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].HallId)
    @Html.Hidden("client", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].BasePlace.PremieraClientId)
    <button type="submit">Make</button>
}
```

Comment: how can we do it in webforms , i am using the routing concept in web forms and want to hide parameters

Answer (score 0):

**How to hide URL Parameters**

If you want to hide URL parameters, you go to debug properties and you select the `radiobutton` option and specify thatc
specificpage:

```
http://localhost:61757/TicketDataUpload/templateupload?projectid=6497&userid=7336
```

This is the parameter URL. If you want to hide like this:

```
http://localhost:61757/Controller/index
```

You have to put in a specific page as when you open the page, it will not display URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

My (kinda ugly) solution: leave the code behind as is, then after the html doc has loaded (at which point the server has already made use of your query string data), use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) in javascript to change the url in the address bar like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let hrefWithoutQueryString = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    // args below are 'state' (irrelevant for me), 'title' (so far, 
    // ignored by most browsers) and 'url' (will appear in address bar)
    history.pushState({ }, '', hrefWithoutQueryString);
});
```

For a split second the query string will appear in the address bar, but after the js above has run, everything including and after the '?' in your url will be gone.

Obviously, a side effect is that it alters your browser's session history but this wasn't an issue for me.

And note that I have passed in an empty state into pushState--again, this was not an issue for me but could cause problems depending on how the routing of your application is set up and whether it makes use of the state variable.