# Don't include empty parameters when submitting form

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

The index method on my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, string sort, int? groupId)
```

For the search functionality, I have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("search", "Search")
        @Html.TextBox("search", ViewBag.Search as string)
        @Html.Hidden("sort", ViewBag.Sort as string)
        @Html.Hidden("groupId", ViewBag.GroupId as int?)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

`Viewbag.Search`, `ViewBag.Sort` and `ViewBag.GroupId` contain the last used parameters. These could be `null` or `""`, and when they are, this is the URL I see when I use the search form:

```
...?search=foo&sort=&groupId=
```

How can I hide these empty parameters from the URL, so it looks like `...?search=foo`?

---

**EDIT:** as Jason Nesbitt said, you can disable hidden field to exclude them from the form. However, I also want to hide empty parameters that come from other things than `hidden` fields, such as regular `input` fields, and also `select` lists.

Comment: can you provide route for this action?

Comment: @Grundy Do you mean the route from the `RouteConfig`? Or the full URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926673/how-can-i-remove-empty-fields-from-my-form-in-the-querystring

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And if you want to stick with the GET method, you can use the fact that browsers won't send disabled fields.  So tie into the onsubmit handler and disable any empty hidden fields like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new {onsubmit="DisableNullFields();"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Test)
    <input type="text" name="TestField" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Push"/>
}

<script>
    function DisableNullFields() {
        $('input[type=hidden]').each(function(i) {
            var $input = $(this);
            if ($input.val() == '')
               $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works great for `hidden` fields, however, what if my search string is empty? Is there a way to disable/hide it when submit is clicked, but before the form is submitted?

Comment: Do the same thing but widen your jQuery selector like $('input') or something.

Comment: Ok that's twice you've done that now when the first answer was a solution to the problem as you originally described it.  Very bad etiquette.  I'm not going to do all of your work for you.  I've pointed you in the right direction and it's your responsibility to figure out how to handle edge cases. Don't try to get me to come back and do more work for you by unchecking my answer as correct. You're on your own.

Comment: Using Jquery's filter:
$('input[type=hidden]').filter(function(){
        return this.val()==''
}).prop('disabled', true);  // attr may work as well.

Comment: Instead of adding the `disabled` attribute, you could've removed the `name` attribute, which would effectively prevent that input element from being submitted in the form.

Answer (score -1):

You could use POST instead of GET. So you could replace the link with a form containing hidden fields for the parameters that you don't want to appear in the query string:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EventOverview", "BaseEvent", new { id = eventInfo.Key.OID, type = eventInfo.Key.XPObjectType.TypeName.GetShortTypeName() }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.Hidden("activeTab", "#scheduleLink")
    @Html.Hidden("session", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].SessionId)
    @Html.Hidden("hall", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].HallId)
    @Html.Hidden("client", eventInfo.Key.EventSchedules[0].BasePlace.PremieraClientId)
    <button type="submit">Make</button>
}
```

from Darin Dimitrov answer in :

[hide parameters passing to controller in address bar (URL rewrite or something else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221697/hide-parameters-passing-to-controller-in-address-bar-url-rewrite-or-something-e)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but POST is not an option for me in this case.

Comment: Using a POST (non-idempotent) request for read-only GET (idempotent) operations is an anti-pattern. One example is that your users won't be able to use the Back button properly. The consumer of your application should be able to understand what your application does, by looking at which HTTP method you use for each operation. More info: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html