# Show only not empty parameters in query string when sumbitting form

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First of all I already saw this: [Don't include empty parameters when submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656809/dont-include-empty-parameters-when-submitting-form)

But in form you can have not only input but also select for example and what if someone have Javascript disabled? Isn't there a better way to hide empty parameters?

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Vehicles" asp-action="Index" method="get" >
<p>
    <select asp-for="Length" asp-items="Model.Lengths">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>

    Brand: <input type="text" asp-for="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
</form>
```

Now if I picked length from select box and clicked filter, I have this url in the browser window:

```
https://localhost:44358/Vehicles?Length=15&Search=
```

but I want this:

```
https://localhost:44358/Vehicles?Length=15
```

or if I only searched brand without picking length I want to have this:

```
https://localhost:44358/Vehicles?Search=Mercedes
```

Is there some helper tag like adding to form `hide-empty="true"` or something like that? Any ready to use element or just simple solution for this simple problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the form method to post?

Comment: If i change it to post then there won't be ANY parameters at all, not only empty ones AND it is anti-patern to use post if it doesnt change anything on server.

Comment: I don't know is there any helper or not, but you can use javascript or jquery to customize your submit form

Answer (score 1):

If you insisit on achieving this requirement, you could try to disable the input which is empty. For disabled field, it will not generate the query string.

Try something like :

```
<form asp-controller="Vehicles" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        Brand: <input type="text" id="Search" name="Search">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" onclick="return DisableNullFields();"/>
    </p>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisableNullFields() {
        $('input').each(function(i) {
            var $input = $(this);
            if ($input.val() == '')
            $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```