# Store an url that will later be used to redirect to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a view which will serve as a common place for many actions. I want to be able to redirect to it, then after a few actions to send back to the original action. Follow my example, you'll understand what I mean.

When I call this view, I go with the following line:

```
return RedirectToAction("SearchItemsToAdd", new {@_currentUrl = Request.Url});
```

I thought that passing the url as parameter would allow me to send back to the action, but I **also need the ID of the item.**, which I do not have with the Request.Url.

So the `_currentUrl` string is carried along in the views and, when a user clicks on a `back` button, I want to be able to redirect to the original action and pass the ID of the item that was used.

So far I have done this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUrl))
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(_currentUrl) && _currentUrl.Length > 1 &&
    _currentUrl.StartsWith("/") &&
    !_currentUrl.StartsWith("//") &&
    !_currentUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
    {
        return Redirect(currentUrl);
    }
}
```

But it does not work because I do not have the ID of the item. Here's, for example, the controller action which starts the call and to which I want to be able to redirect later on:

```
public ActionResult EditPack(int? _packID, PackInfo _packToEdit, string _submitButton)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
    {
        if (_packID == null)
        {
            TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = MessageDomain.ID_PROBLEM;

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayListPacksToManage");
        }

        if (_packID == 0)
        {
            TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = MessageDomain.ID_PROBLEM;

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayListPacksToManage");
        }

        PackInfo pack = mPackManager.GetPackByID((int)_packID);

        pack.mDateModified = DateTime.Now;

        return View(pack);    
    }

    if (_submitButton == "Details")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ViewPackDetails", new {@_packID = _packToEdit.mPackID});
    }

    if (_submitButton == "Delete")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DeletePack", new {@_packID = _packToEdit.mPackID});
    }

    if (_submitButton == "Add Cards")
    {
        _packToEdit = mPackManager.RefreshPack(_packToEdit);

        _packToEdit.UpdateStatus();

        Session[PACK_CREATION_ITEM] = _packToEdit;

        return RedirectToAction("SearchItemsToAdd", new {@_currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath});
    }

    _packToEdit = mPackManager.RefreshPack(_packToEdit);

    _packToEdit.UpdateStatus();

    return View(_packToEdit);
}
```

So when my user finishes his job and want to go back to edit, I want to be able to call the `Edit` controller action and pass the parameter. How could I do that?

Comment: use ViewBag. I guess viewBag is what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I have no problem transferring the url as my example states it, but I do not know how to carry the "structured" url (Action / Controller / Parameters). I could create a dictionary that I would store in the session and pass it along, but I'd be cheating and I wanna learn how routing works.

Comment: sorry mate I am not sure what you mean? if you want the ID then you can make a hidden ITEM @Html.Hidden in the view which keep track of the ID of the page you are in , so when you go to edit page it will post this ID along the other elements, to you can use that to edit the object. have a look at this example to see how to use hidden parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221697/hide-parameters-passing-to-controller-in-address-bar-url-rewrite-or-something-e

Comment: Hey, that's pretty neat and more like what I'm looking for! I'll check this out.

Comment: Cool I am happy I could help you. All the best ;)